# Checking if alteast one of the text box is filled - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

From the HTML and JQuery below, I am trying to check if at least one the text box has value. It is working just fine.

I would like to know if there is any better and shorter approach to achieve the same.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <input type="text" id="text1"/>

     <input type="text" id="text2"/>

     <input type="text" id="text3"/>

     <input type="text" id="text4"/>

    <input type="text" id="text5"/>

    <button onclick="checker();" >Check</button>        
    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
function checker(){

    var text1 = $('#text1').val().length;
    var text2 = $('#text2').val().length;
    var text3 = $('#text3').val().length;
    var text4 = $('#text4').val().length;
    var text4 = $('#text4').val().length;
    var text5 = $('#text5').val().length;

    if (text1==0 && text2==0 && text3==0 && text4==0 && text5==0)            
    {            
         alert('atleast one of the field should be filled');   
    }
}
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/uaLxfrqc/2/

Comment: The `>` markdown notation is used to convert things into block quotes. Please don't use these to decorate links.

Comment: `$('input:text', $('#content')).filter(function($el) {return $el.val().length>0}).size()>0` <<< selects all text input fields inside the div#content, reduce the set of elements by filtering it and check the size>0

Comment: @TamilSelvan But that will check if any one of the field is not empty and I am trying to check if anyone of the field is filled.

Comment: @BigB, not being empty is the same as being filled according to your example code.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this in better way:

```
var textboxes = $('[id^=text]');
var emptytextboxes = textboxes.filter(function(){
  return this.value == "";
});

if(textboxes.length == emptytextboxes.length){
   alert('atleast one of the field should be filled');  
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ucwfmfhn/)**

Comment: FIlter is slower than iterating through each input type element. I'd suggest my answer better.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the "textboxes" class to each input types, and iterate through them with this tested and working snippet.

```
function checker(){
var bool = false;


$('.textboxes').each(function() {
  if (!$(this).val() == '') {
       bool = true;
  }
   });
    alert(bool)
}
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/uaLxfrqc/5/) for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
var isEmpty= false;
$("input[type=text]").each(function() {
      if($(this).val().length > 0)
         {
            isEmpty = true;
            return false; //break out of the loop
         }
});  


if(!isEmpty ){
   alert('atleast one of the field should be filled');  
}
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Luthando/ucwfmfhn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,though havent tested it,

```
function checker(){
    var x="";
    $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="")
            x=x+"y";
    });

    if(x.length>0)            
    {            
         alert('atleast one of the field should be filled');   
    }
}
```